# How to access a input tag value(Name) of a login form in client.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I don't know how to explain this but:

I'm making a chat application using socket.io and NodeJS (Express) - Everything went well, I used to give a prompt to enter the name, so it was easily accessible as `const name = prompt("Enter your name");`

But now i decided to use a login page instead of just a prompt, I made an input tag form.

Here comes the main problem: I've two JS files, client.js and Server.js

When i input my name and press Enter, the pages redirects to the main application, so here comes the tougher part: How do i access that input name such that i can use that name as a variable in client.js?

Like, i can easily access that input name in Server.js by using body-Parse - by just using `req.body.name` but what if i need that same name in Client.js

I'm putting up my both files. Please have a look.

Forgive me for such a mess xd.

**Client.js :**

```
const socket = io();
const form = document.getElementById("sendContainer");
const messageInput = document.getElementById("messageInput");
const messageContainer = document.querySelector(".container");
const name = prompt("Enter your name");
var audio = new Audio("sound.mp3");

const append = (message,position)=>{
  const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
  messageElement.innerText = message;
  messageElement.classList.add("message");
  messageElement.classList.add(position);
  messageContainer.append(messageElement);
  if(position==="left"){
      audio.play();
  }

}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  const message = messageInput.value;
  append(`You: ${message}`, "right");
  socket.emit("send", message);
  messageInput.value = "";
})




socket.emit('new-user-joined', name); //This is where i need the name so that server side can access the name


socket.on("user-joined", (name)=>{
append(`${name} joined the chat`, "right");
})

socket.on("recieve", (data)=>{
append(`${data.name}: ${data.message} `, "left");
})

socket.on("left", (name)=>{
  append(`${name} has left the chat`, "left");
})
```

**Server.js:**

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


const path = require("path");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);
const PORT = 3000 || process.env.PORT;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
const users = {}

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/signup.html");
})

// app.get('/signup.html', function(req, res) {
//   const name = req.body.firstName;
// });

app.post("/", (request,respond)=>{

  respond.sendFile(__dirname +"/public/chat.html");
})






io.on("connection", (socket)=>{
  socket.on("new-user-joined", (name)=>{
    console.log("New User", name);
    users[socket.id] = name;
    socket.broadcast.emit("user-joined", name);
  });

  socket.on("send", (message)=>{
    socket.broadcast.emit("recieve", {message: message, name: users[socket.id]})
  });


socket.on("disconnect", (message)=>{
  socket.broadcast.emit("leave", users[socket.id]);
  delete users[socket.id];
});


});
server.listen(PORT, ()=>{
  console.log("Server has just started...");
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's me again. So i got no response from anyone. Tried implementing again by myself. And Who-hoo! I figured it out.

I used Qs cdn - A querystring parser that supports nesting and arrays, with a depth limit.

so now, i could simple write it like this:

```
const fullName = Qs.parse(location.search), {ignorePrefixQuery:true});
```

And simply get the first name as:

```
const name = fullName.firstName;
```

and use the name variable wherever possible.